# access xml in solution instead of bin

Tags: asp.net

How would I access the xml in my solution? Usually I have to move it to bin/Debug/...Is there a way to access where it's shown in image (application root)?

[image]

```
XDocument rssFeed = XDocument.Load("sampleFeed1.xml");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `Server.MapPath` ?

```
string path=Server.MapPath("~/samplefeed1.xml");
XDocument rssFeed = XDocument.Load(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work for Default.aspx.
try

```
XDocument rssFeed = XDocument.Load("/sampleFeed1.xml");
```

The Load() method take a uri as it's parameter - if the path is correct it should work.

edit: Shyju has it with the tilde (this finds the root for you)